# Flip a coin multiple times. When the process stops, we see one head. Question, how many tails in expectation?

Tags: probability, means

Intuition says one, but calculation using negative binomial distribution says two. got confused? Help please.

Here is my calculation.

Note that when the process stops, we observe $x$ heads. The process is equivalent to that once we observe the $x+1$ heads, the process stops immediately. So, the number of tails follows the negative binomial distribution with parameters ($x+1$,$1/2$) and its mean is $x+1$.

For the case, $x=1$, on average we observe $2$ tails when the process stops and $1$ head is observed.

Does it make sense? Thank you again!

Comment: Please show your calculation.  We can't comment on what is wrong without seeing it.  Are you implying the head you see is the first one?

Comment: Make sure you are using the formula for the count of *successes before* the first failure, not that for the count of *trials until* the first failure.

Comment: I updated my comments. Can you please take a look again? Thank you.

Comment: Your explanation is confusing.  I had assumed that the process stopped when a head (first head) showed up.  However  your description seems to imply stopping by some other (unstated) rule.

Comment: Hi Herb, sorry for the confusion. There is no stopping rule here. The process stops, then, one head is observed, which can be considered as a condition of the stochastic process. Thank you though!

Comment: If we are not provided a stopping rule, then we cannot form an expectation about how many tails might be observed before the process stops.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to analyze as expected number $(N)$ of tosses for the first head to show up.
Assuming a fair coin $N=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(\frac{1}{2})^n$. To carry out the calculation let $f(x)=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$
This gives us $N=f(\frac{1}{2})=2$  This means that the expected numbe of tails $=N-1=1$.

Comment: Hi Herb, thank you for your detailed explanation. But, this is not about the first head, it is the case only one head is observed when the process stops.

Comment: The process stops with one head, which means the first head!

Comment: It is like this: two products A and B, each customer will buy one with equal probability. At the end of the day, we observe $x$ units of A sold. What is the sales for B in expectation? I think it is also $x$, but calculation says $x+1$. Thank you again!

Comment: What calculation?  I don't get the connection with your original question - expected number of tails before one head.

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be correct, if you are counting the right thing.

You want the expected count of *successes* (tails) *before* the first *failure* (head).  $$X_{r,p}\sim\mathcal{NegBin}(r, p)\implies \mathsf E(X_{r,p})=\dfrac{pr}{1-p}$$

$$X_{1,1/2}=1$$

You may be using the formula for the expected count of *trials until* the first failure.   That counts the head *as well* as the tails.

Comment: Thank you, Graham. Sorry for not explaining my question clearly. Please see about newly added explanation, and help me find out where goes wrong. Many thanks!